# Question about data compression algorithms parameters

Tags: algorithm, parameters

I have a question - can someone share information, about compressions algorithms and parameters, that affects they compression rate ( time is not important)?

For example, I googled the command line arguments for WinRar, but I find only complete list of parameters. Mb someone have usefull links, where listed parameters that actualy affects compression quality? Not only for win-rar, but for compression algorithms in general.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you asking about the parameterisation in the mathematics of the algorithms, or the command-line parameters of compression tools?

Comment: Command-lina parameters of compression tools )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://daily-it.blogspot.com/2007/11/rar-command-line-with-real-world.html, the command line option `-m5` will give the highest compression level for WinRar. Lowest is `-m0`.

Some compression tools have such parameters and others don't.  [gzip](http://persephone.cps.unizar.es/~spd/gzip/gzip_man.html), for example lets you specify --fast, --best, or something in between. You'll have to search around and maybe download other tools with their documentation in order to see what their parameters are.